# Authentication using Google and Facebook in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic 2 app . I would like to implement social login options such as google and facebook. My backend is built on Ruby on Rails API. I believe, I can use `cordova facebook` and `google plugins`  for authentication.

Once the user is authenticated with facebook or google, redirect to backend API and authenticate with `omniauth` end-point setup in my API. This will authenticate the user in my app.

I would like to know if this is the right way to authenticate with google and facebook ? I would appreciate any kind of help on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Give Auth0 a try: http://auth0.com. It really simplifies all login scenarios!

Comment: I have already setup email password authentication in my API,so I didnt want to setup another JWT based authentication system.